# ¿Alguien sabe que pasa con mi Layout en ASP .NET?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

Verán,tengo un problema. He configurado mi archivo ***"BundleConfig.cs"*** para minificar mis estilos y scripts en producción. En este momento estoy en el ambiente de desarrollo. Mi aplicación tenía algunos problemas de performance por las dependencias. En un primer momento tenía páginas y llamaba recursos innecesarios,como hojas de estilo y/o scripts, ahora estoy corrigiendo eso. En esta etapa es que he tenido una traba que no puedo saltarla desde hace un día. Mi página Clientes(listado de los mismos) esta teniendo problemas al cargarse, cosa que no pasa con mi Dashboard; obviamente usan el mismo Layout(Master Page). Yo pienso que es algo referente a mi llamado a *JQUERY* pero aún no doy con la respuesta. Mi proyecto está hecho con ASP .NET MVC 5 y uso Visual Studio 2015. Sería genial si me ayudaran. Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***BundleConfig.cs***

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Acisac
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            /*  ----------------------------------- CSS  ------------------------------------------ */
            StyleBundle bootstrapCSS = new StyleBundle("~/css/bootstrap");
            bootstrapCSS.Include("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css");
            //bootstrapCSS.Include("~/Content/template/tether/tether.min.css");

            StyleBundle mainCSS = new StyleBundle("~/css/mainCSS");
            mainCSS.Include("~/fonts/css.css");
            mainCSS.Include("~/Content/template/main.css");

            //mainCSS.Include("~/Content/template/animate.min.css");

            StyleBundle fontsCSS = new StyleBundle("~/css/fonts");
            fontsCSS.Include(
                "~/fonts/css.css",
                "~/fonts/font-awesome-icons.min.css",
                "~/fonts/ionicons-icons.min.css",
                "~/fonts/material-design-iconic-font.min.css",
                "~/fonts/other-fonts.css"
                );
            StyleBundle materiagrisCSS = new StyleBundle("~/css/materiagris");
            materiagrisCSS.Include("~/Content/materiagris/materia03.css");
            materiagrisCSS.Include("~/Content/materiagris/materia1.css");
            materiagrisCSS.Include("~/Content/materiagris/materia02.css");

            StyleBundle chartsCSS = new StyleBundle("~/css/charts");
            chartsCSS.Include("~/Content/template/charts/chartist.min.css");

            StyleBundle footableCSS = new StyleBundle("~/css/footable");
            footableCSS.Include("~/Util/footable/footable.bootstrap.min.css");

            bundles.Add(fontsCSS);
            bundles.Add(bootstrapCSS);
            bundles.Add(materiagrisCSS);
            bundles.Add(mainCSS);
            bundles.Add(chartsCSS);
            bundles.Add(footableCSS);

            /*  -----------------------------------   JS  scripts ------------------------------------------ */
            /***************************************JQUERY***************************************/
            ScriptBundle jqueryJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/jquery");
            jqueryJS.Include("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js");
            /***************************************BOOTSTRAP***************************************/
            ScriptBundle bootstrapJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/bootstrap");
            bootstrapJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/pluginsGenerales/tether.min.js");
            bootstrapJS.Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js");
            /***************************GENERALES PARA TODA LA APLICACIÓN***************************/
            ScriptBundle mainJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/mainJS");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/pluginsGenerales/jquery.storageapi.min.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/pluginsGenerales/jquery.fullscreen.min.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/pluginsGenerales/pace.min.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/pluginsGenerales/wow.min.js");

            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/scriptsGenerales/main.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/scriptsGenerales/colors.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/scriptsGenerales/functions.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/scriptsGenerales/left-sidebar.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/scriptsGenerales/navbar.js");

            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/comboBoxes.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/Validacion.js");
            /***********************************CASOS ESPECÍFICOS***********************************/
            //GRAFICOS
            ScriptBundle chartsJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/charts");
            chartsJS.Include(
                "~/Scripts/template/charts/Chart.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/template/charts/chartist.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/template/charts/charts-chartist.js",
                "~/Scripts/template/charts/jquery.easypiechart.min.js",
                 "~/Scripts/template/charts/lodash.min.js"
                );
            //FOOTABLE
            ScriptBundle footableJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/footable");
            footableJS.Include("~/Util/footable/footable.min.js");
            footableJS.Include("~/Util/utilitarios.js");
            /****************************************LOGIN****************************************/
            ScriptBundle loginJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/login");
            loginJS.IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/template/login", "*.js");
            /**************************************DASHBOARD**************************************/
            ScriptBundle dashboardJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/dashboard");
            dashboardJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris4/diagramaBarras.js");
            dashboardJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris4/crudInicio.js");
            /***************************************VENTAS***************************************/
            ScriptBundle cotizacionJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/cotizacion");
            cotizacionJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/ConsultasAjax.js");

            ScriptBundle ordenVentaJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/ordenVenta");
            ordenVentaJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/ConsultasAjax.js");
            ordenVentaJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/crudOrdenVenta.js");

            ScriptBundle facturacionJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/facturacion");
            facturacionJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudFacturacion.js");

            //ScriptBundle guiaVentasJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/guiaVentas");
            //guiaVentasJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudGuia.js");
            /**************************************ALMACEN**************************************/
            ScriptBundle guiaAlmacenJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/guiaAlmacen");
            guiaAlmacenJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris3/crudGuia.js");

            //ScriptBundle productoAlmacenJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/productoAlmacen");
            //productoAlmacenJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudProductoAlmacen.js");

            ScriptBundle notaIngresoJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/notaIngreso");
            notaIngresoJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris3/crudNotaIngreso.js");

            ScriptBundle notaSalidaJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/notaSalida");
            notaSalidaJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris3/crudNotaSalida.js");
            /**************************************COMPRAS**************************************/
            //ScriptBundle ordenCompraJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/ordenCompra");
            //ordenCompraJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudOrdenCompra.js");
            /**************************************CUENTAS**************************************/
            ScriptBundle reciboJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/recibo");
            reciboJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudRecibo.js");

            ScriptBundle convenioJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/convenio");
            convenioJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/agregarConvenio.js");
            //convenioJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudConvenio.js");
            /***********************************MANTENIMIENTO***********************************/
            ScriptBundle clienteJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/cliente");
            clienteJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudCliente.js");
            clienteJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/ContactoNuevo.js");
            clienteJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/DireccionNuevo.js");

            ScriptBundle proveedorJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/proveedor");
            proveedorJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris3/crudProveedor.js");

            ScriptBundle empleadoJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/empleado");
            empleadoJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris4/crudEmpleado.js");

            ScriptBundle almacenJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/almacen");
            almacenJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudAlmacen.js");

            ScriptBundle anaquelJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/anaquel");
            anaquelJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudAnaquel.js");

            ScriptBundle familiaJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/familia");
            familiaJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris3/crudFamilia.js");

            ScriptBundle productoMantenimientoJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/productoMantenimiento");
            productoMantenimientoJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudProducto.js");
            clienteJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/AgregarCaracteristica.js");

            ScriptBundle marcaJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/marca");
            marcaJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris3/crudFamilia.js");

            ScriptBundle unidadJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/unidad");
            unidadJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudUnidad.js");

            ScriptBundle cambioJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/cambio");
            cambioJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudTipocambio.js");

            ScriptBundle impuestoJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/impuesto");
            impuestoJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris3/crudFamilia.js");
            /***********************************TRANSPORTE***********************************/
            ScriptBundle etransporteJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/etransporte");
            etransporteJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudEmpresaTransporte.js");

            //ScriptBundle vehiculoJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/vehiculo");
            //vehiculoJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudVehiculo.js");

            //ScriptBundle conductorJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/conductor");
            //conductorJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudConductor.js");
            /***********************************REPORTES***********************************/
            //ScriptBundle reporteJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/reporte");
            //reporteJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudReporte.js");
            /********************************G. DE USUARIOS********************************/
            //ScriptBundle perfilJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/perfil");
            //perfilJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudPerfil.js");

            //ScriptBundle usuarioJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/usuario");
            //usuarioJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudUsuario.js");
            /***********************************CONFIGURACION***********************************/
            //ScriptBundle empresaJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/empresa");
            //empresaJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudEmpresa.js");
            //ScriptBundle serieJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/serie");
            //serieJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudSerie.js");
            //ScriptBundle bancoJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/banco");
            //bancoJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudBanco.js");

            bundles.Add(jqueryJS);
            bundles.Add(bootstrapJS);
            bundles.Add(mainJS);
            bundles.Add(chartsJS);
            bundles.Add(footableJS);
            bundles.Add(loginJS);
            bundles.Add(dashboardJS);
            bundles.Add(cotizacionJS);
            bundles.Add(ordenVentaJS);
            bundles.Add(facturacionJS);
            //bundles.Add(guiaVentasJS);
            bundles.Add(guiaAlmacenJS);
            //bundles.Add(productoAlmacenJS);
            bundles.Add(notaIngresoJS);
            bundles.Add(notaSalidaJS);
            //bundles.Add(ordenCompraJS);
            bundles.Add(reciboJS);
            bundles.Add(convenioJS);
            bundles.Add(clienteJS);
            bundles.Add(proveedorJS);
            bundles.Add(empleadoJS);
            bundles.Add(almacenJS);
            bundles.Add(anaquelJS);
            bundles.Add(familiaJS);
            bundles.Add(productoMantenimientoJS);
            bundles.Add(marcaJS);
            bundles.Add(unidadJS);
            bundles.Add(cambioJS);
            bundles.Add(impuestoJS);
            bundles.Add(etransporteJS);
            //bundles.Add(vehiculoJS);
            //bundles.Add(conductorJS);
            //bundles.Add(reporteJS);
            //bundles.Add(perfilJS);
            //bundles.Add(usuarioJS);
            //bundles.Add(empresaJS);
            //bundles.Add(serieJS);
            //bundles.Add(bancoJS);  
        }
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>ACISAC - @ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="~/Assets/icon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/Assets/icon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

    <!-- CSS -->
    @Styles.Render("~/css/fonts")
    @Styles.Render("~/css/bootstrap")
    @Styles.Render("~/css/mainCSS")
    @Styles.Render("~/css/materiagris")
    <!-- ------ -->
    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/js/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/js/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/js/mainJS")
    <!-- ------ -->
</head>

<body data-layout="empty-layout" data-palette="palette-6" data-direction="none">
    <div class="main">
        <!--header-->
        @Html.Partial("_header")
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <!--content-->
        @RenderBody()
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <!--footer-->
        @Html.Partial("_footer")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Dashboard.cshtml***

-controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using AcisacWeb.CrossCutting.Dominio.Entidades;
using AcisacWeb.Web.Core.Mantenimiento;
using AcisacWeb.Web.Core.Inicio;
using Acisac.Helper;
using Acisac.Tags;

namespace Acisac.Controllers
{

    public class InicioController : Controller
    {
        string username = Helper.SessionHelper.getUsernameUser();

        TipocambioCore TipocambioCore = new TipocambioCore();
        UsuarioCore UsuarioCore = new UsuarioCore();

        [Autenticado]
        public ActionResult Dashboard()
        {
            TIPO_CAMBIO TIPO_CAMBIO = new TIPO_CAMBIO();
            TIPO_CAMBIO.NESTADO = TipocambioCore.ObtenerEstado("2")[0].NESTADO;
            return View(TIPO_CAMBIO);
            //return View();

        }
}
}
```

-view:

```
@model AcisacWeb.CrossCutting.Dominio.Entidades.TIPO_CAMBIO

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@Styles.Render("~/css/charts")

<!--fila de 4 paneles-->
<div class="row">
    ...
</div>

<script>
    function CargaModal() {
        tipoCambio = '@Model.NESTADO';
        if (tipoCambio == 0) {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    };
</script>

@Scripts.Render("~/js/charts")
@Scripts.Render("~/js/dashboard")
```

**Clientes.cshtml**

-controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using AcisacWeb.CrossCutting.Dominio.Entidades;
using AcisacWeb.Web.Core.Mantenimiento;
using Acisac.Tags;
using AcisacWeb.CrossCutting.Dominio.ViewModels;

namespace Acisac.Controllers
{
    [Autenticado]
    public class MantenimientoController : Controller
    {
        string username = Helper.SessionHelper.getUsernameUser();

        AlmacenCore AlmacenCore = new AlmacenCore();
        AnaquelCore AnaquelCore = new AnaquelCore();

        FamiliaCore FamiliaCore = new FamiliaCore();

        ClienteCore ClienteCore = new ClienteCore();
        ContactoclienteCore ContactoclienteCore = new ContactoclienteCore();
        DireccionclienteCore DireccionclienteCore = new DireccionclienteCore();
        TransporteCore TransporteCore = new TransporteCore();
        TipopersonaCore TipopersonaCore = new TipopersonaCore();
        ProductoCore ProductoCore = new ProductoCore();
        TipocambioCore TipocambioCore = new TipocambioCore();
        UnidadCore UnidadCore = new UnidadCore();
        TipoproductoCore TipoproductoCore = new TipoproductoCore();
        TipomonedaCore TipomonedaCore = new TipomonedaCore();
        TipodocumentopersonaCore TipodocumentopersonaCore = new TipodocumentopersonaCore();
        TipodireccionCore TipodireccionCore = new TipodireccionCore();
        ProveedorCore ProveedorCore = new ProveedorCore();
        MarcaCore MarcaCore = new MarcaCore();
        ImpuestoCore ImpuestoCore = new ImpuestoCore();
        PaisCore PaisCore = new PaisCore();
        EmpleadoCore EmpleadoCore = new EmpleadoCore();
        UbigeoCore UbigeoCore = new UbigeoCore();
        CaracteristicaCore CaracteristicaCore = new CaracteristicaCore();
        ProveedorDatosBancariosCore ProveedorDatosBancariosCore = new ProveedorDatosBancariosCore();
        ProveedorContactoCore ProveedorContactoCore = new ProveedorContactoCore();
        ProveedorDireccionesCore ProveedorDireccionesCore = new ProveedorDireccionesCore();
        SedesCore SedesCore = new SedesCore();
        AreasCore AreasCore = new AreasCore();
        CargosCore CargosCore = new CargosCore();

 public ActionResult Clientes(string PDFINICIO, string PDFFIN)
        {
            List<CLIENTE> clientes = new List<CLIENTE>();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PDFINICIO) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(PDFFIN))
            {
                clientes = ClienteCore.Listar();
                return View(clientes);
            }

            if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(PDFINICIO)) && !(String.IsNullOrEmpty(PDFFIN)))
            {
                clientes = ClienteCore.Filtrar(Convert.ToDateTime(PDFINICIO), Convert.ToDateTime(PDFFIN));

                return View(clientes);
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PDFINICIO) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(PDFFIN))
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PDFINICIO))
                {
                    PDFINICIO = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                    clientes = ClienteCore.Filtrar(Convert.ToDateTime(PDFINICIO), Convert.ToDateTime(PDFFIN));
                    return View(clientes);

                }

                else
                {
                    PDFFIN = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                    clientes = ClienteCore.Filtrar(Convert.ToDateTime(PDFINICIO), Convert.ToDateTime(PDFFIN));
                    return View(clientes);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return View(clientes);
            }


        }
}
}
```

-view:

```
@model IEnumerable<AcisacWeb.CrossCutting.Dominio.Entidades.CLIENTE>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Clientes";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row-lg col-md-12">

    <!--cabecera-->
    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="color-default">Clientes</h3>
        <hr />
    </div>

    ...
</div>
<!--  </div> /.main -->

<!-- DETALLE modal -->
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="large-modalLabel" class="modal fade" id="DETALLE_CLIENTE" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
   ...
</div>

<!-- ELIMINAR modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ELIMINAR_CLIENTE" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="small-modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    ...
</div>
<!-- -->

@*@Scripts.Render("~/js/cliente")*@
```

**NOTA**
He notado que al abrir el código fuente de la página y le quito un estilo, mi página aparece,pero desordenada.Así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya inspeccionaste y viste los recursos que se esta tardando en cargar?

Comment: la verdad,no se si tardan en cargar. Solo no aparecen en la vista de Cliente y si en el dashboard. No es la misma master page? debería salir T-T

Comment: Sin código en la pregunta, ¿Cómo podemos ayudarte?

Comment: puse parte del código,es necesario algo más?

Comment: sí, los controladores y lo que renderiza el HTML :)

Comment: no es mi controlador,mencioné que mi aplicación ya estaba lista,solo tengo este problema con los recursos del front end

Comment: considera que entre más datos proporciones, más rápido y más preciso será el proceso de réplica de tu escenario y su correspondiente debugging. Saludos

Comment: es cierto,publicaré mi código